# Apache Flink eventTimeTimer does not trigger even time has passed

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Following this https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/TimerService.html, we are required to use the eventTimeTimer (currenttimestamp + 2 MIN) should trigger the onTimer event but it does not trigger. It only works when I use the processingTimeTimer.

My requirements is to create an alarm sink when an event came in after 2 mins or no event came in at all.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void processElement(AppEvent appEvent,
                           KeyedProcessFunction<UUID, AppEvent, KafkaAlert>.Context context,
                           Collector<KafkaAlert> collector) throws Exception {


    AppEvent firstEvent = appEventValueState.value();

    if (firstEvent == null) {
        if (appEvent.getAppName().equals("My-APP")
                && appEvent.getStatus().equals("SENT")) {

            //register this event
            appEventValueState.update(appEvent);
            long timer = app.getEventTimeMili() + 1000 * 60; // 1 MINUTE
            context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(timer);
            timerState.update(timer);
           // System.out.println(timer);

        }

    }

}

@Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp,
                        KeyedProcessFunction<UUID, AppEvent, KafkaAlert>.OnTimerContext ctx,
                        Collector<KafkaAlert> out) throws Exception {

        AppEvent appEventStateValue = appEventValueState.value();

        KafkaAlert kafkaAlert = new KafkaAlert(appEventStateValue.getUuid(), appEventStateValue.getAppName());
        out.collect(kafkaAlert);

        cleanUp(ctx);

    }




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
                .setTopics("input-topic")
                .setGroupId("my-kafka-group")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))
                .build();

        DataStream<String> streamKafkaSource = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(),
                "Kafka AppEvents");

        DataStream<KafkaAlert> kafkaAlerts =  streamKafkaSource.map(new AppEventMapperFunction())
                .keyBy(AppEvent::getUuid)
                .process(new AppEventKafkaFunction())
                .name("AppEventKafka");



       kafkaAlerts.addSink(new AlertSinkFunction())
               .name("kafkaSink");

        env.execute("Kakfa-AppEvent");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If an event-time timer isn't triggered, it's always because a large enough watermark never arrives.

There are several possible causes:

- you haven't configured a watermark strategy
- you haven't configured the watermark strategy to use idleness detection, and one or more sources is idle (or has no partitions from which to consume)
- even if a watermark strategy does use idleness detection, if all of its sources become idle, then no watermarks will be emitted and the timer will never be triggered